# how to create a rewrite rule that starts with '#'

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am trying to create a rewrite rule in web.config file that starts with "#" character.

I have the following URL "www.example.com/#abcd=http://www.example.com/myfolder/mypage". This URL needs to be redirect to "www.example.com/myfolder/mypage.html".

I have tried the following rules but none seems to be working.

```
<rule name="myRedirect" stopProcessing="true" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" >
    <match url="##abcd=http://www.example.com/myfolder/mypage" ignoreCase="false"/>
    <action type="Redirect" url="myfolder/mypage.html" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

and the following

```
<rule name="myNewRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="cbp=http://www.example.com/myfolder/mypage" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="/myfolder/mypage.html" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
      </rule>
```

But none of the above are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do a redirect based on the hash string. Browser doesn't transmit that part (everything after hash) to the server.

It's called **Fragment identifier** and is client side only. It's not possible in any language unless you are using some browser implementation (or software) which would send that part of URL to the server. Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier